Color div based on Value positive or negative also show text
I made this counter but I wish to color the id="clicks" based on positive or negative value also append text based on this.


     var clicks = 0;
    function clickplus() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
 }
  var clicks = 0;
    function clickless() {
        clicks -= 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
 }
         #btn_plus{
  background-color: #04AA6D; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;}
   #btn_less{
  background-color: red; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;}
<body style="background-color:#F0F0F0">
  <center>
    </br></br></br>
    <h1>
      <p style="color:#002244">COUNT: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
    </h1>
    <button id="btn_plus" type="button" onClick="clickplus()">+1</button>
    <button id="btn_less" type="button" onClick="clickless()">-1</button>
    </center>
    </body>



Can somebody help? id="clicks" color red if negative and color green if positive also show text positive/negative based on this.

Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service, it's to help people with specific code problems. Try coming up with a solution yourself first, and then if you get stuck ask for help. I can assure you that a quick google search will help you accomplish what you're trying to do very quickly.

Pls note that center tag is deprecated. You can check about display flex and how to use it to center elements for example

"[Color] red if negative and color green if positive" - what about zero?

Use document.getElementById("clicks").style.color = color;


<body style="background-color:#F0F0F0">
<center></br></br></br><h1><p style="color:#002244">CONTAGEM: <a id="clicks">0</a></p></h1>
<button id="btn_plus" type="button" onClick="clickplus()">+1</button>
<button id="btn_less" type="button" onClick="clickless()">-1</button>

    
    </center>
    </body>
    <script>
    var clicks = 0;
    function setColorAndText(clicks){
      let color = (clicks<0)?"red":(clicks>0)?"green":"black";
      let appendText = (clicks<0)?"negative":(clicks>0)?"positive":"";
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks + " " + appendText;
      document.getElementById("clicks").style.color = color;
    }
    
    function clickplus() {
        clicks += 1;
        setColorAndText(clicks);    
    }
  
    function clickless() {
        clicks -= 1;
        setColorAndText(clicks);           
    }
    </script>
    
    <style>
         #btn_plus{
  background-color: #04AA6D; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;}
   #btn_less{
  background-color: red; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;}
    </style>




way to repetitive code

Here is a modern script using delegation eventListener and proper CSS (center is very deprecated)
Also I swapped the buttons since humans normally see negative values left of 0


const container = document.getElementById('centerDiv');
const clickCounter = document.getElementById('clicks');
const posNeg = document.getElementById('posneg');
let clicks = 0;

const clickIt = (e) => {
  let tgt = e.target.closest('button.btn');
  if (!tgt) return; // not one of the buttons
  let increment = tgt.id === 'btn_plus' ? 1 : -1;
  clicks += increment;
  clickCounter.textContent = clicks;
  posNeg.classList.toggle('neg', clicks < 0);
  posNeg.classList.toggle('pos', clicks > 0);

};

container.addEventListener('click', clickIt);
body {
  background-color: #F0F0F0
}

#centerDiv {
  max-width: fit-content;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#btn_plus {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  /* Green */
}

#btn_less {
  background-color: red;
}

.pos::after {
  color:  #04AA6D;
  content: 'Positive'
}
.neg::after {
  color: red;
  content: 'Negative'
}
<div id="centerDiv">
  <h1>
    <p id="counter" style="color:#002244">COUNT: <a id="clicks">0</a> <span id="posneg"></span></p>
  </h1>
  <button id="btn_less" class="btn" type="button">-1</button>
  <button id="btn_plus" class="btn" type="button">+1</button>
</div>




Simply create a CSS class such as .negative that contains color: red. Then you can use element.classList.toggle() to add or remove the class depending if the statement is true or false. The text positive and negativecan be added as pseu-element through CSS using::afterandcontent`:


let count = 0;

const BUTTONS = document.querySelectorAll('button');

BUTTONS.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    switch (this.id) {
      case 'btn_plus':
        count++;
        break;
      case 'btn_less':
        count--;
        break;
    }
    clicks.value = count;
    clicks.classList.toggle('negative', (count < 0));
  })
})
body {
  background-color: #FOFOFO;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

div{
  color: #002244;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
  output {
    color: green;
    &.negative {
      color: red;
      &::after {
        content: ' negative';
      }
    }
    &::after {
      content: ' positive';
    }
  }
}

#btn_plus {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#btn_less {
  background-color: red;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
<body style="background-color:#F0F0F0">
    <div>COUNT: <output id="clicks" role="spinbutton">0</output></div>
    <button id="btn_plus" type="button">+1</button>
    <button id="btn_less" type="button">-1</button>
</body>



